# How to access individual records with Firebase/angularFire (angular app)

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Sorry if this is a massively noob question but I'm new to Firebase (though it seems awesome so far).

I have a list of books saved to Firebase from within an Angular app. I can display these on screen fine using the following code:

```
var db = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.xxxxx.com");
$scope.books = $firebase(db);
```

Then I loop through the books and spit them out into a list.

When I click on each book I want it to takes me to view that displays the book information. Before Firebase I did this by:

```
.controller('BookDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Books) {
  $scope.book = Books.get($stateParams.bookId);
})
```

and then spitting the info out on screen.

How can I do the same in Firebase as the books have no id's but have random strings as keys.

I've looked through the docs but have either missed it or I'm looking at things the wrong way...

Any help would be great, thanks

Adding screenshot of firebase forge - I need to access an individual book, how can I get these random IDs firebase uses for keys/id's?

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue. Basically I was getting the array index instead of the random key because I uses $asArray instead of $asObject https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-extending-factories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize $firebase for this:

```
$scope.book = $scope.books.$child( bookId );
```

But it's not strictly necessary, as the main purpose of AngularFire is to automate a lot of the list management aspects. You could easily go right to the Firebase API if all we want is a specific book:

```
var fb = new Firebase('https://kato-sandbox-books.firebaseio-demo.com');
var bookId = 'book1';
$scope.book = null;
fb.child(bookId).on('value', function(snap) {
   $timeout(function() { $scope.book === snap.val(); });
});
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/F4Xxa/)

Comment: Sorry I should have said, the bookId is gone now I'm using firebase. Firebase uses its own random string for each book like the picture I've added above. Therefore how can I get a individual book using this random string from firebase?

Comment: In fact I could just store the books isbn number which would be unique and access it via that $scope.book = $scope.books.$child( isbn );

Comment: First of all, the books are all contained in `$scope.books` since you've pointed that to a `$firebase` containing all the book data. You can simply iterate the key/value pairs and utilize the data. A list of just keys can be obtained using $getIndex(). In ng-repeat, just use `ng-repeat="(id,book) in books"` All of this is covered in detail in the angularFire docs.

Comment: Is there any harm navigating to a individual book by using it's fb key - http://localhost:8100/#/tab/book/-JOk4bpY7J4qkCCglXz5 for example?

Thanks for your help